# Program that prompts the user for a non-negative integer n, and then writes a sum of the even digits of n

Tags: python, while-loop

I want a program that sums the even numbers of a bigger number using while function.

Exemple :
Number is : 12345 
Print : 6 (2+4)

This is what i wrote so far:

```
num = int(input("Introduce a non negative number: "))
if num % 2 == 0:
    sum += num

print("sum")
```

Comment: `for i in str(number): if int(i) % 2 == 0:`? Would something like that work?

Comment: As this is a school assignment, I will vote to close this issue and ask you tiago to ask your teacher for guidance. These assignments are more meant to teach you concepts rather than trying to find the solution. So you're going about this all wrong.

Comment: Why do you need a `while`? (Also, possibly related: it seems to be missing from your attempt.)

Answer (score 1):

## I can't stress this enough

When doing school assignments, the whole idea with assignments is to teach you concepts, not solutions. There's a reason why you were given this assignment, asking others to solve it for you - **is not the way to go**.

Go back to your teacher, and ask for help if something is unclear. But because others start posting solutions I might as well just keep mine here.

---

Skipping the conversion to an early integer, will allow you to iterate over it as a string, and grab one number a a time.

```
num = input("Introduce a non negative number: ")
total = 0
for i in num:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        total += int(i)

print("sum:", total)
```

You can then use your original logic, with some minor modifications.
Since for whatever reason, you're only allowed to use `while` and not `for`, you'd have to just adapt a bit.

```
num = input("Introduce a non negative number: ")
total = 0
i = 0
while i < len(num):
    if int(num[i]) % 2 == 0:
        total += int(num[i])
    i += 1

print("sum:", total)
```

While I'm at it, after reading my code again. I am quite sure that a `while` loop here is the least pretty solution to this problem. But from a teaching standpoint there might be some benefit here. But I'd recommend going with the `for` loop if at all possible.

Comment: thank you for the help, but i cant use 'for' only while and if

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas: Is this a school assignment? Also, would be a fun opportunity to use `math.abs` for error handling on the input for instance.

Comment: yes it is a school project

Comment: is just an homework exercice to train. im just stuck and these explainations help me clarify. thanks

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas If you want me *(who's a professional teacher)* to explain the psychology and methods involved in teaching students stuff, you're welcome to have a chat with me :) Even home assignments have a real and important mission, to jog your memory of the things you've learned. If you're stuck, it's probably because you missunderstood a concept and it's fundamentals. Which will give you **HUGE** issues later on if you don't grasp it now. So go back, ask for clarification what the difference is between `for` and `while` and why there's virtually no difference (why you got the task).

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas I should also mention, I started out with the same situation. Got stuck, wanted to find help. And it's way easier to just ask someone to "solve" it and try to learn from it. So it **is** a way of learning, the "why" in your help is important tho. Are you asking because you didn't understand the concept, or because you did and you're having actual execution issues. In this case, it's not the later :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
# split the number to list of digits
digits_list = list(input("Introduce a non negative number: "))

total = 0

# loop over the digits list and pick a digit till the list is empty
while digits_list:
    digit = digits_list.pop()
    if int(digit) % 2 == 0:
        total += int(digit)
print(total)
```